# Redirect and then alert

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, redirect

I'm processing something and when the function is successful I would like to redirect to another page and there show the alert "Function successful".

I'm using CodeIgniter, Javascript and Bootstrap

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: How are you processing this? Was it done through a form submission or via AJAX?

Comment: I'm doing this in a separate view and in the success function of an ajax call I redirect to, lets say, an index in which I would like to fire the alert

Comment: The answers below look like they answer you're question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once page X has redirected to page Y, page X is no longer open, so can no longer issue alerts. Your options include:

- don't redirect. (Instead, you may be able to put page Y in an `iframe`; or, simply provide a link to it and let the user decide whether to click.)
- don't alert.
- alert *before* redirecting. (This is basically the same thing. The user can't actually interact with page Y until they've closed the alert, anyway, so it doesn't really matter whether the alert comes before or the redirect or after it.)
- have page Y give the alert. For example, page X can redirect to `http://example.com/path/to/Y/?alert=Function+successful`, and you can design page Y to detect the query string and issue the alert.

Comment: Using codeigniters flashdata sessions are also an option : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

When the functions is successful, redirect and use the body onload event of the new page.  Using a querystring extraction based on another SO answer:

```
if (success)
{
window.location("anotherpage.html?myparm=alertMe");
}
```

...

anotherpage.html

```
<body onload="bodyLoad();">
...
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function bodyLoad()
{
  parmValue = getParameterByName("myparm");
  if(parmValue == 'alertMe')
  {
    alert('Function successful');
  }
}

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me because the page I will load doesn't always receive that notification

Comment: @EnforcerW You could add a querystring variable and check that before the alert